# How to conditionally render wrapping components in React Router 4/5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am migrating an app from react-router version 3 to 5, and am a little stuck trying to figure out the best approach to the following problem.

I have some routes that make use of a wrapping component.

in routerv3 I could do things like

```
const Container = props => 
  <div>
    <header>container1</header>
    { props.children } 
  </div>

const Container2 = props => 
  <div>
    <header>container2</header>
    { props.children } 
  </div>
```

These containers have other function

```
<Route component={Container}>
  <Route path='/container1' component={Page1} />
</Route>

<Route component={Container2}>
  <Route path='/container2' component={Page1} />
</Route>
```

When navigating to `/container1` it would render the `Page1` component with a `Container1` wrapping it, and then on `/container2` it would render `Page1` with `Container2` wrapping it.

However when moving to router v4+ all matching routes are rendered, so what happens is that for example on `/container2` the result is

```
<div>
  <header>container1</header>
</div>
<div>
  <header>container2</header> 
  <Page1 />
</div>
```

Does anyone know of a way to write these "wrapping components" such that they are only rendered if routes match? Or perhaps a better way to do this kind of thing if that's not how react-router 4/5 works.

here is a link to a stackblitz of me trying to figure this out

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jvsdsn?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<Route
  path="/container1"
  render={(routeProps) => (
    <Container>
      <Page1 {...routeProps} />
    </Container>
  )}
/>
<Route
  path="/container2"
  render={(routeProps) => (
    <Container2>
      <Page1 {...routeProps} />
    </Container2>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue because you are still defining the actual path above the container. I want to say that the container wraps multiple paths.

Comment: Container is a component . If you need a generic place to position container instead of wrapping all route renders inside the respective container, you might have to create a prefix for the routes.

Comment: So you're saying i should do something like


```
<Route path='/withcontainer1'>
  <div>container1 content</div>
  <Route path='/restofpath' component={Page1} />
</Route>
<Route path='/withcontainer2'>
  ....
</Route>
```

The problem with this is that it's making the url change just to do something that i could do in RR3